# is this short mirc script correct?

Tags: mirc

```
on @:TEXT:*hello*:#:{ msg $chan test }
```

If I have this right, this automatically will send the word 'test' when any channel admin says any sentence containing the word hello. Is this right?

If not, how does this script need to be changed to do this? Has to respond only to a channel admin.

Comment: You should really keep the mIRC Help File open while you script.. it is an invaluable tool when you're first learning mIRC-Script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
on *:TEXT:*hello*:#:{
    if ($nick isop $chan) msg $chan test
}
```

The first asterisk (`on *:`) is used with your local user levels, it has nothing to do with that user being an Op.

**Edit:** as @rchern states, using `@` in the `<level>` part of the event tells the script to only run if YOU are an Op.

Answer (score 1):

```
on @*:TEXT:*hello*:#: msg # this will send just for @
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't what you want.  (Which hopefully you discovered yourself because you tested it right?)

`on @:TEXT` reacts when **you** are an op on the channel, it has nothing to do with the user who triggered the event.

Try this:

```
on *:TEXT:*hello*:#:{
    if ($nick isop #) { 
        msg # test
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks. Is there a way to have it work on a variety of keywords? like instead of just hello, it works on hi, hello, goodbye, and see you

Comment: @Matt, you would need to do `on *:TEXT:*:` and then test inside the if block for ops only.  Perhaps a RegEx or something else.

Comment: well its mostly just to give a 'goodbye' to a certain op who always leaves too quickly to manually say goodbye, and multiple keywords are to respond to her various goodbye things. If I just use the same script multiple times on my remote.ini with a different keyword, would it work the same way?